# Java process determining executing user's NT groups

Tags: java, active-directory, kerberos, active-directory-group

I'm aware I can call out to Active Directory and do queries provided I have a cleartext username and password. (I don't want to do that)

In VB, I can set authorisation levels by NT group - and the user doesn't have to enter their password nor, store it in a text file. (My understanding is that this has access to the Windows AD ticket).

I also know I can shell out to the command line and parse the output - to get the users groups - this is problematic.

How can I replicate getting the executing user's NT groups without a password in Java?

(It is beginning to sound like I'll have to call the Win32 API with JNA to get the kerberos ticket - I'm hoping there is a simpler way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split up your question in two because you're mixing *authentication* with *authorization*. Kerberos works very pleasently with Java on Windows with some caveats due to MS. Having said that use the Kerberos ticket with the provided principal to authenticate against AD and retrieve the user's `memberOf` values to see in which groups the user is in.

Comment: Could you give a hint about the caveats?

Comment: First part done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721939/java-process-for-authentication-on-windows-against-ad-kerberos

Comment: The caveats are that 
  
1. you have to tamper with the registry because Windows is blocking access to the LSA to obtain the session ticket (TGT) to request service tickets. Google for.
2. you have have to maintain a krb5.conf just like on unix.

Comment: Awesome - any hints on what the registry change is - or do I need to ask another question?

Comment: Please try to be more active in your investigation, took me 10 seconds to find the answer to the first question here in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239495/windows-propagation-of-credentials-to-java-desktop-application